# Delayed messages in Slack

Tags: time, slack

Hello is there a command or app for slack that lets me schedule a message to be sent to a channel at a given time?

**I don't want to /remind someone**, but to send a direct message or chat message.

e.g. group is busy but needs to look at a problem in a month from now.

Comment: Web Hook API to external script/application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this app to easily send scheduled and self-destruct messages in Slack.
https://timy.website

Comment: I get "[...] is not a valid command."

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey Hi! You should use something like this. /send test message in 5m

Comment: Turns out, the problem is: you need to install timy (in slack, channel settings > add an app), but the search for "timy" yields no results. Instead, on the page you referenced (http://timy.thusitha.site) click on "add to slack," and you need to authorize the app before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Saw this project that will send a message at a given time.  Sounds like what your looking for functionally.  It runs outside of slack though

https://gist.github.com/harperreed/c8caaa69b187fd242bf2

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule slack messages using this - https://slackscheduler.com
It is an app that need's to be added to your workspace (same as giphy etc), but once it's added you can schedule messages using the /schedule command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official slack APIs https://api.slack.com/messaging/scheduling which basically schedules sending internally in the slack backend or you can use 3rd party tools, like https://thetopchat.com/ for example